# How to create an array of points in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, python-2.7

I have a *master point* in following projection system:

```
WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_45N
WKID: 32645 Authority: EPSG

Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting: 500000.0
False_Northing: 0.0
Central_Meridian: 87.0
Scale_Factor: 0.9996
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0.0
Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_WGS_1984
Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
Datum: D_WGS_1984
Spheroid: WGS_1984
Semimajor Axis: 6378137.0
Semiminor Axis: 6356752.314245179
Inverse Flattening: 298.257223563
```

Now i want to create 15 points toward north,15 points toward east,15 points toward west,15 points toward  south at 500m distance interval centering *master point*.These point has attribute to be populated in attribute table

Now how to create these points

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at the Create Fishnet tool?  That should do the point creation (as labels).

Comment: Sir fishnet does not creates point only polyline and polygon

Comment: It also has an option to create labels - from its tool help:  "In addition to creating the output fishnet, a new point feature class is created with label points at the center of each fishnet cell if the Create Label Points parameter is set to LABELS (Checked). The name of this feature class is the same as the output feature class with a suffix of _label and is created in the same location."